# JavaScript - How to sort array based on other array order

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have this array:

```
let productKeys = [ "aff_link", "availability", "brand", "date_add", "date_upd", "description", "image_link", "link", "price", "product_type", "title" ];
```

And another array called `preDefinedHeader`:

```
let preDefinedHeader = ['image_link', 'title', 'price', 'brand', 'link'];
```

Now, I want to sort the `productKeys` array based on the `preDefinedHeader` array key order only if any `preDefinedHeader` key exist in `productKeys` array.

so the output should be now;

```
['image_link', 'title', 'price', 'brand', 'link', 'aff_link', 'availability', 'description', 'date_add', 'date_upd', 'product_type'];
```

I know how to sort normally is something like:

```
productKeys.sort()
```

But can not get any idea how to sort like I want. Please help me.

Comment: See [Javascript - sort array based on another array](/q/13304543/4642212) — `productKeys.sort((keyA, keyB) => preDefinedHeader.indexOf(keyA) - preDefinedHeader.indexOf(keyB));` is a start. You can try using this code along with an understanding of how [`sort`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) and [`indexOf`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) work.

Comment: @SebastianSimon Thanks for that. I am using this now: `productKeys.sort(function(a, b){  
  return preDefinedHeader.indexOf(a) - preDefinedHeader.indexOf(b);
});` But doesn't return anything.

Comment: How do you test the return value? The array `productKeys` itself is being modified. Have you logged it?

Comment: @SebastianSimon https://codeshare.io/eVyVZr. Check this please. I got a new array but the order is not correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the code in the suggested link as a start, but you need to take account of the fact that some of the values in `productKeys` are not in `preDefinedHeader`. When that occurs, you want to sort those values to the end of the list, so you need to return a positive number if `a` is not found (`productKeys.indexOf(a) == -1`) and a negative number if `b` is not found, or `a.localeCompare(b)` if both are not found. Otherwise you sort based on the `indexOf` values. This functionality can be implemented as below:

```js
let productKeys = ["aff_link", "availability", "brand", "date_add", "date_upd", "description", "image_link", "link", "price", "product_type"];

let preDefinedHeader = ['image_link', 'title', 'price', 'brand', 'link'];

productKeys.sort((a, b) => {
  let ia = preDefinedHeader.indexOf(a)
  let ib = preDefinedHeader.indexOf(b)
  if (ia == -1) {
    if (ib == -1) return a.localeCompare(b)
    return 1
  }
  else if (ib == -1) {
    return -1
  }
  return ia - ib
});

console.log(productKeys)
```

Comment: Yea. thats the output I am looking for :)

Comment: I found a issue. For e.g. I don't have `title` key in `productKeys`. Now, I can see the output inclues that `title` key but it shouldn't

Comment: @Shibbir that won't happen - see my edit, I've removed `title` from `productKeys` and it is not in the output

Comment: Can you tell me what is the key point I need to learn from this function?

Comment: `sort` functions have to return positive if the first value (`a`) is "greater than" the second (`b`), negative if the first value is "less than" the second, and 0 if they are "equal". So to sort something to the end, you should always return a value that indicates that value is "greater than" the value it is being compared to. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#description

Answer (score 2):

You could sort by the index or with a large value to keep the other items at the same place.

```js
const
    getOrder = s => preDefinedHeader.indexOf(s) + 1 || Number.MAX_VALUE,
    productKeys = [ "aff_link", "availability", "brand", "date_add", "date_upd", "description", "image_link", "link", "price", "product_type", "title" ],
    preDefinedHeader = ['image_link', 'title', 'price', 'brand', 'link'];

productKeys.sort((a, b) => getOrder(a) - getOrder(b));
console.log(productKeys);
```

Answer (score 0):

I use filter(), includes(), sort(), concat(). You can omit the sort() if no need to sort the array after filter().

```
let productKeys = [ "aff_link", "availability", "brand", "date_add", "date_upd", "description", "image_link", "link", "price", "product_type", "title" ];

let preDefinedHeader = ['image_link', 'title', 'price', 'brand', 'link', 'test'];

let newPreDefinedHeader = preDefinedHeader.filter(e => productKeys.includes(e));
console.log(newPreDefinedHeader);
let filteredArr = productKeys.filter(e => !newPreDefinedHeader.includes(e));
let arr = newPreDefinedHeader.concat(filteredArr.sort((a, b) => a - b));

console.log(arr);
// ["image_link", "title", "price", "brand", "link", "aff_link", "availability", "date_add", "date_upd", "description", "product_type"]
```

Comment: What if there are values in `preDefinedHeader` which are not in `productKeys`?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I have amended the code to take your input into consideration. It can omit values which are not in productKeys. Thanks

Comment: It seems from OPs comments on my answer that they want that functionality.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I have amended the codes. It seems working fine. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
let productKeys = [ "aff_link", "availability", "brand", "date_add", "date_upd", "description", "image_link", "link", "price", "product_type", "title" ];

let preDefinedHeader = ['image_link', 'title', 'price', 'brand', 'link'];

const productKeySet = new Set(productKeys);
const output = []

for (const item of preDefinedHeader) {
    if(productKeySet.has(item)) {
        output.push(item)
        productKeySet.delete(item)
    }
}
let arrayWithProperOrder = [...output,...productKeySet]
```

You could do something like this. Not sure if its the most efficient way though.

Answer (score -1):

Here is my take on it:

```js
let productKeys = [ "aff_link", "availability", "brand", "date_add", "date_upd", "description", "image_link", "link", "prices", "product_type", "brand", "title" ];
let ord = ['image_link', 'title', 'price', 'brand', 'link'];

// val returns a numeric string ("000"..."004") if contained in ord, otherwise the original string
const val=e=>{let i=ord.indexOf(e); return i>-1?(1000+i).toFixed(0).slice(1):e; }
console.log("comparison values:",productKeys.map(e=>`${e} => ${val(e)}`)); // shows the comparison values for productKeys

const res=productKeys.sort((a,b)=>val(a).localeCompare(val(b)));
console.log("sorted array:",res)
```

I modified the sample data to demonstrate further edge cases:

- `price` is now `prices` (therefore not all of the `predefinedHeader` values are now available in the `producKeys` array
- `brand` occurs twice (and will be seen twice in the resulting array too)

My approach will fail, when there are other numeric strings in the `productKeys` array, as they will be treated in the same way as the "special" values in `ord`.

In comparison, @Nick's approach works more reliable - here his version again, using ternary operators:

```js
  let productKeys = [ "aff_link", "availability", "brand", "date_add", "date_upd", "description", "image_link", "link", "prices", "product_type", "brand", "title" ];
  let ord = ['image_link', 'title', 'price', 'brand', 'link'];

const res=productKeys.sort((a, b) => { // Nick's approach (see above) with ternary operator:
  const ia = ord.indexOf(a), ib = ord.indexOf(b);
  return ia==-1 
    ? ib==-1 
       ? a.localeCompare(b) 
       : 1 
    : ib==-1 
       ? -1 
       : ia - ib
});
console.log(res)
```